# Jquery and CSS Libaries not loading in accordance with Cordova

Tags: html, css, jquery-mobile, cordova

I've just created a very simple native app *(**jquery-1.8.3.min.js** ,**jquery-mobile-1.3.2.min.js** and **jquery-mobile-1.3.2.min.css** by making these libraries as local files)* with **HTML5 +JavaScript + Cordova** , which can activate the native camera on a button click & save the clicked picture.I am trying to load the Jquery mobile Libraries and Css (i.e jquery ) in this file to make the UI appearance good . Including these scripts and style sheets in `<head>` tag but its not loading . No changes in the Native App as from the basic Html and Javascript one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems like i have found the solutuion for my problem. I tried the following libraries **jquery-1.8.3.js is compatible with **jquery-mobile-1.2.1.js and **jquery-mobile-1.2.1.css.
I think that **jquery-mobile-1.3.2.js was not compatible with **jquery-1.8.3.js , thats why it was not fetching the css.
Thought of sharing this , hope its helpful !
Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

A suggestion is to check to see if you are adding them to the correct "www" folder.  They need to be added to the one in the `platform > ios`, or `platform > android` not to the one outside of the "platform" folder.

Comment: I am working in adt bundle so focusing on Android , and Yeah i am adding these files in Assets folder --> www folder . in this case also , do i need to check for this platform folder ?

Comment: "Invalid byte 1 of 1-byte UTF-8 sequence. " I am getting this error ,does this relates to not fetching the libraries anyways ?

Comment: No issues . we can ponder over it later , meanwhile i got the solution and the problem was the library compatibilty , mentioned above . Thanks !

Answer (score 0):

Are you referencing them properly locally? If your structure is as follows;

index.html

- css

-- jquery.css

- js

-- jquery.js

You need the following in head:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/jquery.css" />
```

And this in body:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.js"></script>
```

Let me know if this doesn't help and if so please share some more information and how you have referenced the files.

Comment: Yeah , i tried it both the ways ! I mean placing all the files in the same folder as well as in different folder. when tried with multiple folders i opted the same format as you mentioned above. But its not making any difference.

Comment: Can you quote the relevant parts of your index.html? I am using Jquery in several phonegap projects so it surely should work.

Comment: showing how you are referencing you libraries and CSS would be helpful to troubleshoot for you.

Comment: <head>
 <title>Page Title</title>
   <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, minimum-scale=1, user-scalable=yes">
   <link rel="stylesheet" href="jquery.mobile-1.3.2.min.css" />
  <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8" src="jquery-1.8.3.min.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8" src="jquery-mobile-1.3.2.min.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8" src="cordova-2.5.0.js"></script>

Comment: This is when all the files are placed in same www folder under assets folder.

Comment: "Invalid byte 1 of 1-byte UTF-8 sequence. " I am getting this error ,does this relates to not fetching the libraries anyways ?